# Is there a difference between setting FD_CLOEXEC on a file descriptor vs. passing it to posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose?

Tags: c++, c, process, posix, spawn

I have some code that's using `posix_spawnp(3)` to create a new process. I want to set the child's `stdin` to read from a certain file descriptor so before the `posix_spawnp()` call I'm setting up a `dup2` file action:

```
ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&file_actions, fd_for_stdin, 0);
```

Then I have no more use for `fd_for_stdin` in the child process so I believe I should close it. To achieve that is there a difference between adding a call to `posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(3)` versus adding a call to `fcntl(2)` to set `FD_CLOEXEC`? My understanding is that these two code snippets (error checking omitted) should have the same result - is that right, or am I missing something?

```
posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&file_actions, fd_for_stdin, STDIN_FILENO);
posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&file_actions, fd_for_stdin);
posix_spawnp(..., &file_actions, ...);
```

Versus:

```
posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&file_actions, fd_for_stdin, STDIN_FILENO);
fcntl(fd_for_stdin, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
posix_spawnp(..., &file_actions, ...);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec of [`posix_spawnp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html#) says:

> 1. The set of open file descriptors for the child process shall initially
>    be the same set as is open for the calling process. The child process
>    shall not inherit any file locks, but all remaining attributes of the
>    corresponding open file descriptions (see fcntl), shall remain
>    unchanged.
> 2. The signal mask, signal default actions, and the effective user and
>    group IDs for the child process shall be changed as specified in the
>    attributes object referenced by attrp.
> 3. The file actions specified by the spawn file actions object shall be
>    performed in the order in which they were added to the spawn file
>    actions object.
> 4. Any file descriptor that has its FD_CLOEXEC flag set (see fcntl) shall
>    be closed.

There's nothing in the description of the close action that suggests that it does anything different from the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag. In both cases they just close the descriptor when spawning.

However, using `posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose()` gives you control over precisely when the descriptor is closed, since the file actions are performed in the order that they're added, while `FD_CLEXEC` is always processed last.